# iOS iPhone 5 CMMotion deviceMotionUpdateInterval issue

Tags: ios, ios4, cmmotionmanager

I have been using CMMotionManager successfully with iOS 6.0 and 4th generation iPhone and iPod touch.  The new iPhone 5 seems to run at an update interval that is twice as long as specified.  If the kTIME_INTERVAL is 0.0125, I see actual intervals of about 0.021.

When I set the interval to 0.0125 / 2.0, the actual timer intervals are close to 0.013 which is what I want.

Is anyone seeing similar behavior with CMMotionManager on iPhone 5?

```
CMMotionManager *motion;

motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = kTIME_INTERVAL; // iPhone 4 and 4th gen devices

if (isDevice5thGeneration) {
    // iPhone 5 iOS 6 seems to run motion at twice the update interval (half as fast), so need to set interval at half to get desired interval
    motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval / 2.0; // iPhone 5 KLUDGE 
}
NSLog(@"Start motion recording deviceMotionUpdateInterval: %f", motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval);

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] retain];

CMDeviceMotionHandler motionHandler = ^(CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion, NSError *error) {
    //NSLog(@"motion handler");
    if (isRecordingMotion) {
        [self processMotion:deviceMotion];
    }
};
[motion startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:motionHandler];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't want to claim that I have an answer (just starting a project with CMMotionManager), but I always use explicit float values for contants.  So, I would use 0.0125f so I can trust the compiler.  Meanwhile, your question is very helpful to me +1.